# A Recurrence Equation From a Game

Tags: recurrence-relations, game-theory

$a_n=a_{n-1}(a_{n}-a_{n-2}+1)$

The above equation is defined in $[0,m]$ st. $a_{0}=0$ and $a_m=1$. It turned up as I was trying to analyze a simple richman game.

I have managed to solve the equation as a system for small m's, however it becomes harder as m grows, even though the values seem to follow a nice distribution. I would quite like to know if there was a way to solve it, or perhaps approximate it using differential equations or similar.

**Edit:** This is a plot given $m=10$:

[image]

It is symmetric such that $a_{m-n}=1-a_{n}$

Comment: What do you mean by *nice distribution*? Sharing your thoughts here might help.

Comment: You are right. I was referring to the smooth shape of the plot above + the symmetry property. At least it doesn't seem like a sequence likely to do anything 'crazy'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as $a_n - a_{n-1} =a_n a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}a_{n-2}$.  Now you can telescope.

$$a_n - a_{n-1} =a_n a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}a_{n-2}$$
$$a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} =a_{n-1}a_{n-2}-a_{n-2}a_{n-3}$$
$$...$$
$$a_2 - a_1 =a_2 a_1-a_1 a_0$$

Summing all of that and simplifying you have $a_n  = \dfrac{a_1}{1-a_{n-1}}$ or $a_{n-1} = 1 - \dfrac{a_1}{a_n}$.  Thus $a_2 = \dfrac{a_1}{1-a_1}$ and $a_3 = \dfrac{1-a_1^2}{1-2a_1}$

Similarly, given $a_m = 1$, you have $a_{m-1} = 1-a_1$ and $a_{m-2} = 1 - \dfrac{a_1}{1-a_1} = \dfrac{1-2a_1}{1-a_1}$

Thus we can express every term in terms of $a_1$, in two ways depending on which path we take. To find $a_1$, we need to have the forward and backward paths meet at some point, equate the terms and solve the resulting equation.  However this doesn't look easy given the expressions coming up, unless we can use some symmetry in early terms itself.  Perhaps someone else can help more.

Comment: Your formula yields $a_{\frac{m}{2}+1}=2a_1$ for even $m$. As $a_{\frac{m}{2}+1}$ seems to be tending towards $\frac{1}{2}$ for large $m$s, it looks like $a_1$ tends towards $\frac{1}{4}$. Solving your $a_n=\frac{c}{1-a_{n-1}}$ in mathematica and letting c go towards $\frac{1}{4}$ gives the simple formula $\frac{n}{2+2n}$. This might be a good approximation for large $m$s if we combine it with the symmetry property.

Answer (score 1):

@Thomas ahle: Did you solve it yet? Please show me your methods because I also met a similar problem above. 
$\left\{\begin{matrix}
S_{n}=S_{n-1}+T_{n-1}\\ 
T_{n-1}=C_{n-3}+D_{n-4}\\ 
C_{n-3}=E_{n-4}+F_{n-4}\\ 
E_{n-4}=K_{n-5}+T_{n-5}\\ 
F_{n-4}=E_{n-7}+D_{n-7}\\ 
D_{n-7}=H_{n-8}+F_{n-8}\\ 
H_{n-8}=S_{n-11}+C_{n-11}\\ 
K_{n-5}=S_{n-7}+C_{n-8}
\end{matrix}\right.$
Now, I'm trying to solve it by matrix form but it is so hard. Particularly, find generating matrix and characteristic polynomial.